# Shiny app does not work and seems to not read the server side code at all

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to R (using R Studio) and am looking to build a shiny app as a user interface for my homemade trading platform. I can see the menu, tabs etc. of the app but none of the action buttons work, nor does it read the data tables I refer to. The ui.R and server.R are in the same folder. The code is as below. The app is being hosted locally.

I have had a look at several questions here and have followed all requisite instructions. My working directory is the folder of the app (in this case the app's name is data import and I have made this folder as my wd).

UI.R

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Resalysis Traders",
           tabPanel("Refresh&summary",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        actionButton("acbutton1", "Refresh price database"), #Download and append EOD prices
                        actionButton("acbutton2", "Show table"), #Show price table
                        actionButton("acbutton3", "Calculate returns") 
                        ),
                      mainPanel(
                       DT::DTOutput("BSE_stock_data")
                      )

                    ))
)
```

Server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
                timeseriesStocksBSE <- read.csv(file="./Data/timeseriesStocksBSE.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
output$BSE_stock_data <- DT::renderDT({
                  observeEvent(input$acbutton2,{

               datatable(timeseriesStocksBSE)})

              })



})
```

I receive no error messages when I run the App. I just receive a webpage with my action buttons, menus etc. which do not perform any of the assigned tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cannot check whether your folder structure is correct yet I fixed the error in your code. The observeEvent belongs outside of the render function. Here you go:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Resalysis Traders",
                         tabPanel("Refresh&summary",
                                  sidebarLayout(
                                    sidebarPanel(
                                      actionButton("acbutton1", "Refresh price database"), #Download and append EOD prices
                                      actionButton("acbutton2", "Show table"), #Show price table
                                      actionButton("acbutton3", "Calculate returns") 
                                    ),
                                    mainPanel(
                                      DT::DTOutput("BSE_stock_data")
                                    )
                                    
                                  ))
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  timeseriesStocksBSE <- iris
  observeEvent(input$acbutton2,{
    output$BSE_stock_data <- DT::renderDT({
      
      datatable(timeseriesStocksBSE)})
    
  })
  
  
  
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but it doesn't solve the issue unfortunately. The app remains unresponsive.

Comment: does the code above work for you? Here I have everything in one file so if it does it might be something in your folder structure or file naming. you can try to just split the code above in your existing files and see if it still works

Comment: If I split the file it doesnt, but I also made a new app.R single file and copied your file and it worked. It also worked when I substituted an already loaded R data frame in place of iris dataset. But, when I tried to read a csv file (as in my original code) then the app didn't work. The app interface showed for a second and then the web page went completely blank

Comment: so the app does not find your files. put a `browser()` right before you load the data, go to the console and type `read.csv("")` and tab inside of the quotes to see where the app searches for the file and where it actually is. good luck